# Android Bluedroid BLE: Certain phones aren't receiving notifications from GATT server?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I recently used the Bluedroid API to connect a Huawei Honor to an ESP32 over BLE. It worked out great. *Everything* worked, including notifications. Now I've tried again to use the same code with the following two devices:

1. Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 7.0)
2. Wileyfox Swift (Android 7.1.2)

Detecting and connecting to the ESP32 from these phones is fine. But no matter what it seems I do, I just cannot receive notifications. There are countless questions about this on StackOverflow. But they generally cover the following mistakes:

- Not setting up the characteristic descriptor in the `onServicesDiscovered` callback
- Not calling `gatt.writeDescriptor` after enabling notifications
- Not trying to place a small delay in the `onServicesDiscovered` callback before writing to the characteristic descriptors

I've done all these things, and feel like I've exhausted all the usual options. I've gone through the ESP32 code and can see it confirms it is dispatching notifications. So I feel like bar using some kind of packet sniffer to check if the Bluetooth packets are actually sent, it has to be a problem on the Android side of things.

---

#### GATT Callback

```
/* @brief: Callback for Bluetooth GATT events */
    private BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange (BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

            if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else {
                DeviceBluetoothManager.this.onBluetoothDisconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered (BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            //super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            boolean didConnect = (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS);

            // Try this arbitrary sleep thing
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (didConnect == false) {
                DeviceBluetoothManager.this.onBluetoothDisconnect();
            } else {
                DeviceBluetoothManager.this.isDeviceConnected = true;

                // Update Service and Characteristic objects
                service = gatt.getService(uuid_device_service);
                characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(uuid_device_characteristic);

                // Set whether characteristic is enabled
                if (gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true) == false) {
                    Log.e("BLE", "Characteristic could not be enabled!?");
                    return;
                }

                // Set the write-type for the characteristic
                characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);

                // Show all descriptors for debugging purposes
                if (characteristic.getDescriptors().size() > 0) {
                    for (BluetoothGattDescriptor d : characteristic.getDescriptors()) {
                        Log.i("BLE", "BluetoothGattDescriptor: " + d.getUuid().toString());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("BLE", "No BluetoothGattDescriptors");
                    return;
                }

                // Now setup the descriptor to enable notifications (aperiodic feedback from device)
                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor =
                        characteristic.getDescriptor(uuid_device_characteristic_descriptor);
                Log.i("BLE", "Getting descriptor: " + descriptor.getUuid().toString());
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                if (gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor) == false) {
                    Log.e("BLE", "Error writing descriptor setting!");
                    return;
                }

                // Inform delegate (on disconnect will also inform delegate)
                if (DeviceBluetoothManager.this.delegate != null) {
                    DeviceBluetoothManager.this.delegate.onBluetoothConnect(didConnect);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                             characteristic) {
            //super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);

            // Extract response data
            byte[] characteristic_value_data = characteristic.getValue();

            // Log for debug reasons
            Log.i("BLE", "Received characteristic data:");
            log_hex_buffer(characteristic_value_data);

            // If a delegate is set, then call it with the data
            if (delegate != null) {
                delegate.onCharacteristicChanged(characteristic_value_data);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                          characteristic, int status) {
            Log.i("BLE", "Characteristic Read Event");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                           characteristic, int status) {

            // Release the write semaphore
            System.out.println("Releasing write-semaphore!");
            DeviceBluetoothManager.this.writeSemaphore.release();

            // Log error if didn't succeed
            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.e("BLE", "Last write to device characteristic did not succeed");
            } else {
                Log.i("BLE", "Characteristic write successful!");
            }

            // Update delegate on outcome of write operation
            if (delegate != null) {
                delegate.onCharacteristicWrite((status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS));
            }
        }
    };


    /* @brief Handles disconnection. Cleans up internal variables; Notifies delegate if set */
    private void onBluetoothDisconnect () {
        gatt.disconnect();
        this.isDeviceConnected = false;
        this.service = null;
        this.characteristic = null;
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.onBluetoothConnect(false);
        }
    }
```

I have the following UUIDs in use:

```
    // UUID of the single device service in the broadcasted profile
    private UUID uuid_device_service = intToUUID(0x00FF);

    // UUID of the multipurpose characteristic of the device service
    private UUID uuid_device_characteristic = intToUUID(0xFF01);

    // UUID of the descriptor for the characteristic
    private UUID uuid_device_characteristic_descriptor = intToUUID(0x2902);
```

And when I actually run the application, I am able to connect, and receive callbacks to everything except `onCharacteristicChanged` where I expect notifications to be received.

---

#### Logcat

The following is outputted from Logcat when the application runs, connects, and is supposed to be receiving notifications

```
2019-11-22 16:53:41.197 24217-24217/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 24:6F:28:43:AF:XX, auto: true
2019-11-22 16:53:41.197 24217-24217/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothAdapter: isSecureModeEnabled
2019-11-22 16:53:41.198 24217-24217/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
2019-11-22 16:53:41.198 24217-24217/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=6eb8a948-dda5-4f6f-a485-80980cc8dc34
2019-11-22 16:53:41.300 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
2019-11-22 16:53:43.562 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=24:6F:28:43:AF:XX
2019-11-22 16:53:43.576 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 24:6F:28:43:AF:XX
2019-11-22 16:53:43.938 24217-24338/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=24:6F:28:43:AF:XX interval=24 status=0
2019-11-22 16:53:44.214 24217-24234/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=24:6F:28:43:AF:XX interval=6 status=0
2019-11-22 16:53:44.450 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=24:6F:28:43:AF:XX Status=0
2019-11-22 16:53:45.452 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
2019-11-22 16:53:45.454 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android I/BLE: BluetoothGattDescriptor: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
2019-11-22 16:53:45.455 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android I/BLE: Getting descriptor: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
2019-11-22 16:53:45.471 24217-24235/com.example.ekg_android D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=24:6F:28:43:AF:XX interval=24 status=0
```

Is there anything specific to these phones that makes implementing BLE different? I feel it is unlikely that both would exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Install the *nRF Connect* app on the affected devices and test if it receives notifications. If it works, the problem is likely on the ESP32 side. If not, it's likely in your Android code.

Comment: @Codo Thank you for suggesting that. I was able to figure out that it wasn't the Android application, but the GATT server running on the embedded device that was misconfigured. I have since resolved the issue. If you want, you can write a response suggesting to use the app to trigger characteristic notifications/indications and I will accept it as an answer because it helped me find the source of the problem.